# How should I fit a new breaker for a subpanel in my main panel?

Tags: subpanel

I want to add a 100 amp subpanel in my basement with a 60 amp breaker next to my main panel which is 200 amp. I want to run my basement lights on their own breaker. Right now my garage and basement are on the same double 15 amp breaker.

What I need to know is what breaker I should remove to make my subpanel a 60. Here are pics of my box and what they feed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whichever you like. Decide what circuits you want to move to the new box (based on cable length, etc.) and there's your answer.

Comment: This seems like an opinion question.  Make sure to get a nice big subpanel so you never have to do this again! Remember large aluminum is proven safe, and #2 aluminum wire (90A) is quite a bit cheaper than #6 copper.  You can put it on a cheaper 60A breaker and upgrade to a 90A breaker if you need the extra capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 on the bottom right would be my choice, why they are small 15 amp and one looks open.

Use those 2 positions to feed the garage then remove the tandem and put the 20 amp in that location if there are 2 in use there another choice would be better but this would be my choice with what I can see.